# Mind Boggled : Not exactly a fixed number of Trials, but Independent Events?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, conditional-probability

And so, I have a math question for my stats homework that goes like this :

**A car dealer has a list of 15 cars. The probability of selling one car during a typical week is 40%. The chance of selling any one car is independent of selling another. Find the probability of selling more than 4 cars in one week.**

I've been having a headache trying to solve this - is it even possible for the probability of one car to be sold to remain independent throughout, especially when the number of cars left in the set of 15 will gradually diminish as each subsequent one is sold?

I have also tried using the Binomial distribution method to solve this, and got a result of 0.78 probability of P(X=5 ≤ 15) which seems highly unlikely.

Set of 15(no. of trials?)
p=0.4 (?)
X(random variable) = 5 ≤ 15 (since more than 4 in this case, means selling at least 5, and at most 15)

Also on second thought, i do not think this qualifies as binomial, unless each car being sold will be replaced and resulting in a purely fixed number of 15 cars.

Anyone here has any idea how to work on this?

Comment: Sure.  think of each car as an independent coin toss...$H$ means "sale".  It's not a fair coin, but even so.  That said, it is not clear that your model is physically sensible....but it makes perfectly good mathematical sense.

Comment: We have to assume that the random variables are independent. That´s the information of the exercise. Thus we use the binomial distribution with $p=0.4$ and $n=15$. Then $P(X>4)=1-P(X\leq 4)\approx 78.27\%$.

Comment: I think the issue you have is with the underlying model.  I don't believe that car sales are independent.  You only have so many buyers.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is actually my math homework for a stats class. I'm still trying to wrap my head around this question because it seemed odd (and the professor hasn't even taught us on binomial probability yet when we were given this homework)

Comment: @user219358 For me your result of 78% seems right under the condition that the chance of selling any one car is independent of selling another.

Comment: I'm not sure if i am thinking too deep into the set of 15 cars - I'm facing lots of doubts if they actually qualify as a "fixed number of trials"? If they do then the binomial method will be correct, but if in the case it is not, what other possible method is there?

Comment: @user219358 It seems that the car dealer has a list of 15 car models. That means that all the car  models are  available even if a car has been sold just now. In this sense a sell of a car doesn´t affect the probability of selling of another car. Another approach I cannot think of.

Comment: I think what is assumed in this question is there are 15 cars total in inventory. I think $X$ which is the total number of cars sold is $X \sim Binomial(n=15,p=.4)$ It's as if you flipped 15 coins all at once and each has a probability of landing heads is $.4$. That's my interpretation but I could be wrong. I'm a beginner so I could be wrong but overall I think this is a sloppily written problem. I wouldn't call out the prof though... gotta win the war not the battle =)

Comment: I'm confused by your notation. Is "$X=5\le15$" your way of saying $5\le X\le15$? If not, what on earth does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

One difficulty is to understand what is meant by "[T]he probability of selling one car during a typical week is 40%."

(a) Does that mean the probability is $0.4$ that any one car is sold?

(b) Does it mean that the probability is $0.4$ that exactly one car is sold in a week?

(c) Does it mean the probability is $0.4$ that at least one car is sold in a week?

(d) Or, does it mean the average number of cars sold per week is $0.4,$ and then find the probability sales *in a week* exceed 4?

---

This is an interesting problem in building probability models for real life situations. I'll show several (speculative) possible ways to
approach the problem.

One approach is to choose interpretation (c) and
let the number $X$ of cars sold in a week have a Poisson distribution with appropriate rate $\lambda.$
$$P(X \ge 1) = 1 - P(X = 0) = 1 - e^{-\lambda} = 0.4,$$
so that $\lambda = 3.2189.$

This is an approximate model with individual car sales
modeled as random events.  It is easy to use R to find
the distribution of $X.$  [Ignore numbers in brackets.]

```
x = 0:15;  pdf = round(dpois(x, 3.2189), 4)
cbind(x, pdf)
       x    pdf
 [1,]  0 0.0400
 [2,]  1 0.1288
 [3,]  2 0.2072
 [4,]  3 0.2223
 [5,]  4 0.1789
 [6,]  5 0.1152
 [7,]  6 0.0618
 [8,]  7 0.0284
 [9,]  8 0.0114
[10,]  9 0.0041
[11,] 10 0.0013
[12,] 11 0.0004
[13,] 12 0.0001
[14,] 13 0.0000
[15,] 14 0.0000
[16,] 15 0.0000
```

Technically, there is no limit on how many cars might
be sold, but realistically there is almost no chance of selling more
than 13. Also, $P(X > 4) = 0.2228.$

```
1 - ppois(4, 3.2189)
[1] 0.2227613
```

Somewhat similar methods can be used to make binomial and Poisson models for alternative interpretations,
solving for either Poisson $\lambda$ or binomial $p.$
[I share your misgivings about binomial models, but
I think *any* model will have to make interpretations and assumptions, maybe binomial models are OK as approximations.]

For the model $\mathsf{Binom}(n = 15, p=.4),$ the
distribution is shown below:

```
x = 0:15;  pdf = dbinom(x, 15, .4)
cbind(x, round(pdf,4))
       x       
 [1,]  0 0.0005
 [2,]  1 0.0047
 [3,]  2 0.0219
 [4,]  3 0.0634
 [5,]  4 0.1268
 [6,]  5 0.1859
 [7,]  6 0.2066
 [8,]  7 0.1771
 [9,]  8 0.1181
[10,]  9 0.0612
[11,] 10 0.0245
[12,] 11 0.0074
[13,] 12 0.0016
[14,] 13 0.0003
[15,] 14 0.0000
[16,] 15 0.0000
```

As several have said, this leads to $P(X > 4) = 0.7827.$

```
1 - pbinom(4, 15, .4)
[1] 0.7827223
```

Using interpretation (d) and $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 0.4),$ one obtains
$P(X > 4) = .000061.$ Most of the probability
is for lower sales.

```
1 - ppois(4, .4)
[1] 6.124333e-05
```

---

If your professor intended this problem to provoke you into thinking about thorny issues in making realistic probability models for real life situations, then I guess the problem is a success.

Comment: Given that it is a class problem, I am sure the intended interpretation is a, the chance of selling each car is $0.4$ independent of whether other cars are sold.  Any relationship to the real world is not important.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Probably so. Another clue is that the binomial distribution had not yet been covered, but evidently has now. A 'bridge' question.

Answer (score 1):

my professor has just got back to me - and yes, it is indeed binomial!

The Poisson method looks really interesting though. Thanks everyone for all the insights!